# Adding media to Tweeter

Tags: api, twitter, oauth, media, share

Can someone tell me what does my gallery requiere so when a user Tweets the url, the picture o video apears in the tweet, like so:

Like this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaLmM.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out how...

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards